# Searching for Equivalence Among Elements of a List

Tags: python, list, loops, append

I have the following code in place

```
Trans_Func = [['s1', '@', 's2'], ['s1', '@', 's4'], ['s2', '0', 's2'], ['s2', '1', 's3'], ['s3', '0', 's3'], ['s3', '1', 's3'], ['s3', '2', 's3'], ['s4', '1', 's4'], ['s4', '2', 's4'], ['s4', '2', 's5']]
new_rules = []
for i, j in Trans_Func:
    if i[0] == j[0] and i[1] == j[1]:
        #operation to append the new rule
print(new_rules)
```

I am trying to create a new list that contains elements from Trans_Func only when the first strings are equivalent, the second strings are equivalent, but the third strings are different. My expected output for new_rules is:

```
new_rules = [['s1', '@', 's1, s4'], ['s4', '2', 's4, s5']]
```

I just do not know how to loop through Trans_Func in an attempt to inspect multiple elements at the same time.

Comment: Are you supposed to compare *ever* element to every other element, or just elements that are adjacent in the list?

Comment: Should not the 1st resulting sublist be `['s1', '@', 's2, s4']` ??? It seems like you mistyped `'s1, s4'`

Answer (score 1):

Here you go

```
for i in range(len(Trans_Func)):
    IF i<len(Trans_Func)-1:
        if Trans_Func[i][1]==Trans_Func[i+1][1] and Trans_Func[i][2]==Trans_Func[i+1][2]:
            #operation to append the new rule
```

Comment: Thank you. I understand the process behind this code and should certainly be working, but when running it I am given an index error, specifically that the list index is out of range. Do you know why this would be?

Comment: try my edited answer. It checks if i<len(Trans_Func) so that i+1 does not go out of range

Comment: That was my first guess: also tried it with a while loop and increasing the length by 1, but it still gives the same error.

Comment: i just edited my answer to check i<len(Trans_Func)-1. This is because if length of list is 10, range(len(Trans_Func)) would return values from 0 to 9

Answer (score 1):

You can use a dictionary to manage matching pairs as keys and accumulate the 3rd strings in a list as the values.  Then run through the dictionary to isolate pairs that have more than one associated 3rd string:

```
d = dict()
for s1,s2,s3 in Trans_Func: d.setdefault((s1,s2),[]).append(s3)
new_rules = [ [s1,s2,", ".join(ss)] for (s1,s2),ss in d.items() if len(ss)>1 ]

print(new_rules)
[['s1', '@', 's2, s4'], ['s4', '2', 's4, s5']]
```

Answer (score 0):

Give your variables a proper names (lowercase and meaningful), say `trans_list` (for ex.).
With effective *generator expression* and `zip` function:

```
trans_list = [['s1', '@', 's2'], ['s1', '@', 's4'], ['s2', '0', 's2'], ['s2', '1', 's3'], ['s3', '0', 's3'],
              ['s3', '1', 's3'], ['s3', '2', 's3'], ['s4', '1', 's4'], ['s4', '2', 's4'], ['s4', '2', 's5']]
new_rules = list([lst_1[0], lst_1[1], lst_1[2] + ', ' + lst_2[2]]
                 for lst_1, lst_2 in zip(trans_list[:-1], trans_list[1:])
                 if lst_1[:2] == lst_2[:2] and lst_1[2] != lst_2[2])
print(new_rules)
```

The output:

```
[['s1', '@', 's2, s4'], ['s4', '2', 's4, s5']]
```